# Ruby and SOAP creating a web service proxy and namespace

Tags: ruby, web-services, powershell, soap, wsdl

I am SOAP novice, but I have been struggling with this for days and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to use Ruby to talk to VMware Site Recovery Manager

I have a powershell script that can successfully use to login. I want to take this powershell script and re-write it in ruby.

Here are the wsdl files:

```
https://srm-vcenter-a:8095/srm?wsdl
```

http://pastebin.com/xJ6AwLaC

```
https://srm-vcenter-a:8095/srm-Service?wsdl
```

http://pastebin.com/nmH5mzdH

The powershell code

```
$Server = "srm-vcenter-a"
$UserName = "administrator"
$Password = "mypw"

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
Write-Host "Connecting to SRM"
$webSvc = New-WebServiceProxy ("https://" + $Server + ":8095/srm-Service?wsdl") -Namespace SRM
$srm = New-Object SRM.SrmService
$srm.Url = "Https://" + $Server + ":9007"
$srm.Timeout = 600000
$srm.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

$srmSvcRef = New-Object SRM.ManagedObjectReference
$srmSvcRef.Type = "SrmServiceInstance"
$srmSvcRef.Value = $srmSvcRef.Type

$srmSvcContent = $srm.RetrieveContent($srmSvcRef)

$srm.SrmLoginLocale($srmSvcRef, $UserName, $Password, $null)

$srmObject = New-Object System.Object
$srmObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -value $Server -Name SRMServer
$srmObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -value $srm -Name SRMService
$srmObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -value $srmSvcContent -Name SRMContent

...
```

I have tried using Savon, soap4r, and handsoap and I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is the Savon code that doesn't work.

```
require 'savon'
require 'rubygems'

client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "https://srm-vcenter-a:8095/srm?wsdl"
  #endpoint "https://srm-vcenter-a:8095/srm-Service?wsdl"
  endpoint "http://srm5-vcenter-a:9007"
  namespace "https://srm-vcenter-a/sdk/srm"
  #proxy "https://srm-vcenter-a:8095/srm-Service?wsdl"
  ssl_version :TLSv1
  ssl_verify_mode :none
  convert_request_keys_to :lower_camelcase
end

message = { username: 'administrator', password: 'mypw' }
response = client.call(:srm_login_locale, message: message)
```

Thanks in advance for all help

Comment: not sure i have the time to help out, but can you please create a pastie containing savon's debug request/response output so that we know what could be going wrong here?!

Comment: here is the error along with the code that was tested http://pastebin.com/p0prLmtg

Comment: your wsdl files contain quite a few imports (which might contain other imports). to test this with a wsdl-based tool like soapUI, i would need all those files. did you try to create a sample request with soapUI and compare it to the request sent by savon?

Comment: no i will try with SoapUI. I'm a complete n00b to this stuff so I  hope I can figure it out. If you want to try it out, do you want the XML files? if so, you can get them here -> http://kendrickcoleman.com/free/srm.xml and here http://kendrickcoleman.com/free/srm-Service.xml

Comment: that's just two if them. the first file contains four schema-imports (e.g. query-types.xsd; search for import tags in those wsdl and xsd files). soapUI needs all those definitions to create a request. i'd suggest you download soapUI, create a sample request and compare it with savon's request. if you can't figure it out, please add the sample request to your question.

Comment: i installed SoapUI but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I loaded in the https://srm-vcenter-a:8095/srm-Service?wsdl and it populated with the list. When I go to the SrmLoginLocale it's asking for a ManagedObjectReference. I'm not sure what I need to pipe. I clicked the form for that particular box, clicked on Get Data -> Project [SRM] -> Create New. For "Specify name of source property to create", i used "srmSvcRef". For "Specify a value for the new property 'srmSvcRef'", i used "SrmServiceInstance". Any ideas? screenshot ->   http://kendrickcoleman.com/free/SRMsoapui.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42738/discussion-between-rubiii-and-kenny-coleman)

Answer (score 0):

Having taken a brief look at your code it appears that in PowerShell you have

```
$srm.SrmLoginLocale($srmSvcRef, $UserName, $Password, $null)
```

While in Ruby you have

```
message = { username: 'administrator', password: 'mypw' }
response = client.call(:srm_login_locale, message: message)
```

In the PowerShell code there are 4 values passed to the SrmLoginLocale method:

1. $srmSvcRef
2. $UserName
3. $Password
4. $null

In the ruby code you are missing the first parameter and the fourth parameter in your call. Try creating the equivalent of $srmSvcRef in ruby. I am not a ruby programmer but I think the code would look *something* like:

```
srm_svc_ref = { value: 'SrmServiceInstance', type: 'SrmServiceInstance'}
message = { _this: srm_svc_ref, username: 'administrator', password: 'mypw', locale: nil}
response = client.call(:srm_login_locale, message: message)
```